# Как вызвать элемент сложного массива?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

В plist(для дальнейшего использования с кордатой) храню список упражнений из трех item, которые в свою очередь содержат названия этих трех комплексов и перечень из нескольких упражнений в каждом комплексе. Файл описания комплексов упражнений

```
import Foundation

class Exersise: NSObject {

var name: String!
var image: String!
var exersiseDescript: String!

init(name: String, image: String, exersiseDescript: String){
    super.init()
    self.name = name
    self.image = image
    self.exersiseDescript = exersiseDescript
}

static var sectionNames: [String] = [] // НАЗВАНИЕ КОМПЛЕКСА УПРАЖНЕНИЙ, ОТОБРАЖАЕТСЯ В НАЗВАНИИ СЕКЦИЙ ТАБЛИЦЫ

static var all: [[Exersise]] = {

    var allObjects: [[Exersise]] = []
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Exersises", ofType: "plist")
    let objects = try! NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!, options: .MutableContainersAndLeaves, format: nil) as! NSArray

    for object in objects {
        sectionNames.append(object["name"] as! String)
        var subArray: [Exersise] = []
        for item in object["items"] as! NSArray {
            subArray.append(Exersise(name: item["name"] as! String, image: item["image"] as! String, exersiseDescript: item["exersiseDescript"] as! String))
        }
        allObjects.append(subArray)
    }
    return allObjects
}()
}
```

Основной контроллер доступа к комплексам упражнений

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

var buyArray = [0]

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Buy") != nil){
        buyArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Buy") as! Array
        print("buyArray = \(buyArray)")
    }
}

@IBAction func firstButton(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Первый комплекс бесплатен")
}

@IBAction func SecondButton(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Куплен второй комплекс")
    buyArray.append(1) // ДОБАВЛЯЕМ КУПЛЕННЫЕ УПРАЖНЕНИЯ В МАССИВ buyArray
    print("buyArray = \(buyArray)")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(buyArray, forKey: "Buy")
}

@IBAction func ThirdButton(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Куплен третий комплекс")
    buyArray.append(2) // ДОБАВЛЯЕМ КУПЛЕННЫЕ УПРАЖНЕНИЯ В МАССИВ buyArray
    print("buyArray = \(buyArray)")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(buyArray, forKey: "Buy")
}
```

}
В третьем контролере отображаем приобретенные упражнения, именно здесь при вызове названия секции выдает ошибку...

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AllExersiseTableViewController: UITableViewController {

private var exersises: [[Exersise]] = []
private var selected: Set<NSIndexPath> = []
private var sectionCount = 1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var allBuy = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE"]
    var buyForTableView = [String]()
    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Buy") != nil){
        buyArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Buy") as! Array
    }

    for element in buyArray {
        buyForTableView.append(allBuy[element])
    }
    print(buyForTableView)

    if buyForTableView == ["ONE"]{
        let index = Exersise.sectionNames.indexOf("ONE")! // Название секции в plist
        exersises.append(Exersise.all[index])
    } else if buyForTableView == ["ONE", "TWO"]{
        var index = Exersise.sectionNames.indexOf("ONE")!
        exersises.append(Exersise.all[index])
        index = Exersise.sectionNames.indexOf("TWO")!
        exersises.append(Exersise.all[index])
    } else if buyForTableView == ["ONE", "THREE"]{
        var index = Exersise.sectionNames.indexOf("ONE")!
        exersises.append(Exersise.all[index])
        index = Exersise.sectionNames.indexOf("THREE")!
        exersises.append(Exersise.all[index])
    } else if buyForTableView == ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE"] || buyForTableView == ["ONE", "THREE", "TWO"]{
        var index = Exersise.sectionNames.indexOf("ONE")!
        exersises.append(Exersise.all[index])
        index = Exersise.sectionNames.indexOf("TWO")!
        exersises.append(Exersise.all[index])
        index = Exersise.sectionNames.indexOf("THREE")!
        exersises.append(Exersise.all[index])
    }
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return exersises.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return exersises[section].count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let object = exersises[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = object.name
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: object.image)
    cell.accessoryType = selected.indexOf(indexPath) != nil ? .Checkmark : .None
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return Exersise.sectionNames[section]
}

private func addWorkout(name: String) {
    let manager = CoreDataManager.defaultManager()
    let workout = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Workout", inManagedObjectContext: manager.managedObjectContext) as! Workout
    workout.creationDate = NSDate()
    workout.name = name
    workout.items = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(selected)
    manager.save()
}
}
```

Вот пример ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кому интересно, ссылка на проект https://yadi.sk/d/Eh4yTEgiukyYT
Всем спасибо за помощь!

Пример не правильного отображения секций к описанному ниже коменту
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас Exersise.sectionNames пустой. При попытке его force unwrap (у вас там '!' стоит) получается unexpectedly found nil

Comment: Уже кучу времени убил на вроде не сложный момент, мозги сломал, но не допру. Подскажите плиз как правильно оформить, чтоб Exersise заполнен был...

Comment: а где и чем вы его заполняете?

Comment: Я извиняюсь, что не правильно ставлю вопрос. Как правильно мне реализовать отображение доступных секций с упражнениями?

Comment: Max, помогали уже не раз по разным темам, помогите плиз решить задачу :(

Comment: что по вашей задумке должно быть в sectionNames?

Comment: В sectionnames - Название комплекса упражнений( отображается в тайтле секции), которая в свою очередь(секция) содержит ячейки с фото и названием упражнений этого комплекса.

Comment: и откуда берется эта информация?

Comment: Данные берутся из plist. Если удобней смотреть в xcode, в самом низу вопроса есть ссылка на проект

Comment: А, теперь въехал. тут надо пошаманить, чтоб разобраться. Завтра напишу, если до этого никто не ответит

Comment: Спасибо, буду ждать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45006/discussion-between-max-mikheyenko-and-artur-skachkov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема у вас в том, что код, который должен заполнить этот самый массив, никогда не вызывается. По этому массив nil и крэшится на force unwrap. Самый простой способ этот массив заполнить - вызвать функцию заполнения, перед тем, как массив использовать.

```
_ = Exersise.all
```

типа такого

Comment: Добавил, теперь работает, это уже супер, но не до конца правильно (( При добавлении например третьего элемента в массив покупок, не добавив сначала второго, при запуске отображает первый и второй, а не первый и третий. indexOf не срабатывает? Для примера добавил скрин в конец вопроса

Comment: Сейчас присмотрелся, оказывается перечень в добавленной секции правильный, от третьей секции. А вот название секции почему то пишет вторую, а не третью. Не пойму